# nodos TreeView con indices en C#

Tags: c#

necesito saber si es posible establecer alguna especie de indice/key a esos nodos, el problema surge porque necesito poder crear más cuentas y si tengo dos cuentas con el mismo nombre me es necesario conocer su ubicación exacta (las cuentas que tenga por padres e hijas).

Entonces si alguien tiene alguna idea o sugerencia bienvenida sea.

[image: muestra todas las cuentas contables]

Comment: Pero a parte de la descripción, almacenas identificador o código de la cuenta!? Ese indice te dará el orden en q se muestran las cuenta dentro de una misma rama del arbol!?

Comment: @Francisco, Gracias por contestar. La idea es llevar un orden para asi poder acomodar los nodos, las cuentas tiene sus padres e hijos y durante la marcha se crearan mas cuentas. Alguien respondio que con el .Tag es posible almacenar objetos, creo que de esa forma de sirve más porque asi almaceno el objeto de tipo cuenta en el nodo y a la hora de pedir el seleccionado podre obtener el objeto cuenta y con ello toda la info. igual si sabes de alguna otra forma me podes contar, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `.Tag` que tiene el objeto `TreeNode`. Mi recomendación sería que utilices números enteros únicos como identificadores, pero viendo tu *TreeView* imagino que provienen de diferentes tablas por lo que tal vez te convenga utilizar pipe lines (`|`) para separar los *identificadores* y posteriormente retomarlos con un `split` de esta manera:

```
TreeNode tnActivo = new TreeNode();

tnActivo.Text = "ACTIVO";
tnActivo.Tag = "1";

TreeNode tnActivoCorriente = new TreeNode();
tnActivoCorriente.Text = "ACTIVO CORRIENTE";
tnActivoCorriente.Tag = "1|1";

TreeNode tnCaja = new TreeNode();
tnCaja.Text = "CAJA";
tnCaja.Tag = "1|1|1";

TreeNode tnBancos = new TreeNode();
tnBancos.Text = "BANCOS";
tnBancos.Tag = "1|1|2";

tnActivoCorriente.Nodes.Add(tnCaja);
tnActivoCorriente.Nodes.Add(tnBancos);

TreeNode tnActivoNoCorriente = new TreeNode();
tnActivoNoCorriente.Text = "ACTIVO NO CORRIENTE";
tnActivoNoCorriente.Tag = "1|2";

tnActivo.Nodes.Add(tnActivoNoCorriente);
tnActivo.Nodes.Add(tnActivoCorriente);
```

Y para recuperarlos puedes utilizar:

```
string[] identificador = tnBancos.Tag.ToString().Split('|');

//DONDE identificador[0] = 1
//DONDE identificador[1] = 1
//DONDE identificador[2] = 2
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias por contestar. Eso es justo lo que estaba buscando pero en lugar de almacenar el indicador que mencionas me sirve mas almacenar el objeto de tipo cuenta, de donde viene la información. anteriormente lo estaba haciendo como indicas pero con la propiedad .FullPath que hace eso mismo que indicas. Tu respuesta me sirvió montones muchas gracias. .